# How to get the data of a "multiselect option" coming from a cell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I created a cell to assemble a "multiple selection option" and inserted it into a view for the user.

Fill in the fields like this:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple id="product">
    <?php foreach ($json["data"] as $product):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $product["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $product["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I added this cell to a user registration form along with other fields!

```
<?= $this->cell('Products');?>
```

**How can I get the information selected by the user and send it to the controller after submitting the form?**
Can I solve this using the cell?

Comment: You need to give the `select` element a name.

Comment: Note that `echo $this->Form->control('product', ['options' => collection($json['data'])->combine('id', 'name')->toArray(), 'multiple' => true])` should give you something at least very close to what you're doing here.